Imported Approval Flow not working
I have a problem with an imported Approval Flow - here's the scenario:
On my test SharePoint site, I created an out of the box Approval Flow for Pages and then modified it. Among other things, in the "For a selected item" trigger, I added several "text inputs" that need to be filled in when adding a new Page to the site. I tested everything and then exported the flow, imported it, and then changed all the URLs to fit my Live site. Here's the problem - when I add a Page and click "Submit for approval", the standard approval panel "Submit for approval" appears - the one that always appears when we select "Require content approval for submitted items?" in versioning settings. Instead, the panel with a multiple fields to fill in should appear - those that were added as text inputs in the flow trigger. But it doesn't. However, when I open the Site Pages library, the imported flow is visible in the context menu for a specific item under Automate -> Power Automate, and it can be triggered.
Why aren't the text inputs associated with the flow showing up when I click "Submit for approval"? Why is the flow not triggering right away when I'm adding a new page?
Should I delete and re-add the trigger? I would prefer to avoid that, because obviously removing the trigger will wipe out a lot of values in the actions, and I'll have to input them again from scratch

In order to better help you solve your problem, it is recommended that you describe your problem in more detail.
